# React Native:-[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError:null is not an object (evaluating '_InCallManager.checkCameraPermission')]

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I have this in my React Native Code:

```
                    import React, {useState} from 'react';
                    import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
                    import {Text} from 'react-native-paper';
                    import {TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';
                    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
                    import {Button} from 'react-native-paper';

                    export default function LoginScreen(props) {
                      const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
                      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);



                      const onLogin = async () => {
                        setLoading(true);
                        try {
                          await AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', userId);
                          setLoading(false);
                          props.navigation.push('Call');
                        } catch (err) {
                          console.log('Error', err);
                          setLoading(false);
                        }
                      };

                      return (
                        <View style={styles.root}>
                          <View style={styles.content}>
                            <Text style={styles.heading}>Enter your id</Text>
                            <TextInput
                              label="Your  ID"
                              onChangeText={text => setUserId(text)}
                              mode="outlined"
                              style={styles.input}
                            />

                            <Button
                              mode="contained"
                              onPress={onLogin}
                              loading={loading}
                              style={styles.btn}
                              contentStyle={styles.btnContent}
                              disabled={userId.length === 0}>
                              Login
                            </Button>
                          </View>
                        </View>
                      );
                    }

                    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
                      root: {
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                        flex: 1,
                        // alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                      },
                      content: {
                        // alignSelf: 'center',
                        paddingHorizontal: 20,
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                      },
                      heading: {
                        fontSize: 18,
                        marginBottom: 10,
                        fontWeight: '600',
                      },
                      input: {
                        height: 60,
                        marginBottom: 10,
                      },
                      btn: {
                        height: 60,
                        alignItems: 'stretch',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        fontSize: 18,
                      },
                      btnContent: {
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        height: 60,
                      },
                    });
```

And this to call the peer:

```
              import React, {useEffect, useState, useCallback} from 'react';
              import {View, StyleSheet, Alert} from 'react-native';
              import {Text} from 'react-native-paper';
              import {Button} from 'react-native-paper';
              import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
              import {TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';

              import {useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';

              import InCallManager from 'react-native-incall-manager';

              import {
                RTCPeerConnection,
                RTCIceCandidate,
                RTCSessionDescription,
                RTCView,
                MediaStream,
                MediaStreamTrack,
                mediaDevices,
                registerGlobals,
                Permissions,
              } from 'react-native-webrtc';

              export default function CallScreen({navigation, ...props}) {
                let name;
                let connectedUser;
                const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
                const [socketActive, setSocketActive] = useState(false);
                const [calling, setCalling] = useState(false);
                // Video Scrs
                const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState({toURL: () => null});
                const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState({toURL: () => null});
                const [conn, setConn] = useState(new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080'));
                const [yourConn, setYourConn] = useState(
                  //change the config as you need
                  new RTCPeerConnection({
                    iceServers: [
                      {
                        urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',  
                      }, {
                        urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',    
                      }, {
                        urls: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',    
                      }

                    ],
                  }),
                );

                const permissionCheck = async () => {
                  const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
                  
                };
                const [offer, setOffer] = useState(null);

                const [callToUsername, setCallToUsername] = useState(null);

                useFocusEffect(
                  useCallback(() => {
                    AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then(id => {
                      console.log(id);
                      if (id) {
                        setUserId(id);
                      } else {
                        setUserId('');
                        navigation.push('Login');
                      }
                    });
                  }, [userId]),
                );

                useEffect(() => {
                  navigation.setOptions({
                    title: 'Your ID - ' + userId,
                    headerRight: () => (
                      <Button mode="text" onPress={onLogout} style={{paddingRight: 10}}>
                        Logout
                      </Button>
                    ),
                  });
                }, [userId]);

                /**
                * Calling Stuff
                */

                useEffect(() => {
                  if (socketActive && userId.length > 0) {
                    try {
                      InCallManager.start({media: 'audio'});
                      InCallManager.setForceSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                      InCallManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                    } catch (err) {
                      console.log('InApp Caller ---------------------->', err);
                    }

                    console.log(InCallManager);

                    send({
                      type: 'login',
                      name: userId,
                    });
                  }
                }, [socketActive, userId]);

                const onLogin = () => {};

                useEffect(() => {
                  /**
                  *
                  * Sockets Signalling
                  */
                  permissionCheck();
                  conn.onopen = () => {
                    console.log('Connected to the signaling server');
                    setSocketActive(true);
                  };
                  //when we got a message from a signaling server
                  conn.onmessage = msg => {
                    let data;
                    if (msg.data === 'Hello world') {
                      data = {};
                    } else {
                      data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
                      console.log('Data --------------------->', data);
                      switch (data.type) {
                        case 'login':
                          console.log('Login');
                          break;
                        //when somebody wants to call us
                        case 'offer':
                          handleOffer(data.offer, data.name);
                          console.log('Offer');
                          break;
                        case 'answer':
                          handleAnswer(data.answer);
                          console.log('Answer');
                          break;
                        //when a remote peer sends an ice candidate to us
                        case 'candidate':
                          handleCandidate(data.candidate);
                          console.log('Candidate');
                          break;
                        case 'leave':
                          handleLeave();
                          console.log('Leave');
                          break;
                        default:
                          break;
                      }
                    }
                  };
                  conn.onerror = function(err) {
                    console.log('Got error', err);
                  };
                  /**
                  * Socjket Signalling Ends
                  */

                  let isFront = false;
                  mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(sourceInfos => {
                    let videoSourceId;
                    for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
                      const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
                      if (
                        sourceInfo.kind == 'videoinput' &&
                        sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? 'front' : 'environment')
                      ) {
                        videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
                      }
                    }
                    mediaDevices
                      .getUserMedia({
                        audio: true,
                        video: {
                          mandatory: {
                            minWidth: 500, // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
                            minHeight: 300,
                            minFrameRate: 30,
                          },
                          facingMode: isFront ? 'user' : 'environment',
                          optional: videoSourceId ? [{sourceId: videoSourceId}] : [],
                        },
                      })
                      .then(stream => {
                        // Got stream!
                        setLocalStream(stream);

                        // setup stream listening
                        yourConn.addStream(stream);
                      })
                      .catch(error => {
                        // Log error
                      });
                  });

                  yourConn.onaddstream = event => {
                    console.log('On Add Stream', event);
                    setRemoteStream(event.stream);
                  };

                  // Setup ice handling
                  yourConn.onicecandidate = event => {
                    if (event.candidate) {
                      send({
                        type: 'candidate',
                        candidate: event.candidate,
                      });
                    }
                  };
                }, []);

                const send = message => {
                  //attach the other peer username to our messages
                  if (connectedUser) {
                    message.name = connectedUser;
                    console.log('Connected iser in end----------', message);
                  }

                  conn.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                };

                const onCall = () => {
                  setCalling(true);

                  connectedUser = callToUsername;
                  console.log('Caling to', callToUsername);
                  // create an offer

                  yourConn.createOffer().then(offer => {
                    yourConn.setLocalDescription(offer).then(() => {
                      console.log('Sending Ofer');
                      console.log(offer);
                      send({
                        type: 'offer',
                        offer: offer,
                      });
                      // Send pc.localDescription to peer
                    });
                  });
                };

                //when somebody sends us an offer
                const handleOffer = async (offer, name) => {
                  console.log(name + ' is calling you.');

                  console.log('Accepting Call===========>', offer);
                  connectedUser = name;

                  try {
                    await yourConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));

                    const answer = await yourConn.createAnswer();

                    await yourConn.setLocalDescription(answer);
                    send({
                      type: 'answer',
                      answer: answer,
                    });
                  } catch (err) {
                    console.log('Offerr Error', err);
                  }
                };

                //when we got an answer from a remote user
                const handleAnswer = answer => {
                  yourConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer));
                };

                //when we got an ice candidate from a remote user
                const handleCandidate = candidate => {
                  setCalling(false);
                  console.log('Candidate ----------------->', candidate);
                  yourConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
                };

                //hang up
                const hangUp = () => {
                  send({
                    type: 'leave',
                  });

                  handleLeave();
                };

                const handleLeave = () => {
                  connectedUser = null;
                  setRemoteStream({toURL: () => null});

                  yourConn.close();
                  // yourConn.onicecandidate = null;
                  // yourConn.onaddstream = null;
                };

                const onLogout = () => {
                  // hangUp();

                  AsyncStorage.removeItem('userId').then(res => {
                    navigation.push('Login');
                  });
                };

                const acceptCall = async () => {
                  console.log('Accepting Call===========>', offer);
                  connectedUser = offer.name;

                  try {
                    await yourConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));

                    const answer = await yourConn.createAnswer();

                    await yourConn.setLocalDescription(answer);

                    send({
                      type: 'answer',
                      answer: answer,
                    });
                  } catch (err) {
                    console.log('Offerr Error', err);
                  }
                };
                const rejectCall = async () => {
                  send({
                    type: 'leave',
                  });
                  ``;
                  setOffer(null);

                  handleLeave();
                };

                /**
                * Calling Stuff Ends
                */

                return (
                  <View style={styles.root}>
                    <View style={styles.inputField}>
                      <TextInput
                        label="Enter Friends Id"
                        mode="outlined"
                        style={{marginBottom: 7}}
                        onChangeText={text => setCallToUsername(text)}
                      />
                      <Button
                        mode="contained"
                        onPress={onCall}
                        loading={calling}
                        //   style={styles.btn}
                        contentStyle={styles.btnContent}
                        disabled={!(socketActive && userId.length > 0)}>
                        Call
                      </Button>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.videoContainer}>
                      <View style={[styles.videos, styles.localVideos]}>
                        <Text>Your Video</Text>
                        <RTCView streamURL={localStream.toURL()} style={styles.localVideo} />
                      </View>
                      <View style={[styles.videos, styles.remoteVideos]}>
                        <Text>Friends Video</Text>
                        <RTCView
                          streamURL={remoteStream.toURL()}
                          style={styles.remoteVideo}
                        />
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                );
              }

              const styles = StyleSheet.create({
                root: {
                  backgroundColor: '#fff',
                  flex: 1,
                  padding: 20,
                },
                inputField: {
                  marginBottom: 10,
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                },
                videoContainer: {
                  flex: 1,
                  minHeight: 450,
                },
                videos: {
                  width: '100%',
                  flex: 1,
                  position: 'relative',
                  overflow: 'hidden',

                  borderRadius: 6,
                },
                localVideos: {
                  height: 100,
                  marginBottom: 10,
                },
                remoteVideos: {
                  height: 400,
                },
                localVideo: {
                  backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
                  height: '100%',
                  width: '100%',
                },
                remoteVideo: {
                  backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
                  height: '100%',
                  width: '100%',
                },
              });
```

Why do i keep getting this error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError:null is not an object (evaluating '_InCallManager.checkCameraPermission')]
```

After Anik Dey Answer iget this stacktrace:

```
                        Error [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'WebRTCModule.peerConnectionInit')]

                    TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'WebRTCModule.peerConnectionInit')

                    This error is located at:
                        in CallScreen (at SceneView.tsx:122)
                        in StaticContainer
                        in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
                        in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
                        in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
                        in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                        in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
                        in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                        in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
                        in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                        in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
                        in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
                        in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                        in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
                        in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
                        in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
                        in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
                        in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
                        in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                        in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
                        in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
                        in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
                        in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                        in View (at Card.tsx:538)
                        in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
                        in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:620)
                        in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                        in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
                        in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:613)
                        in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                        in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
                        in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:495)
                        in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
                        in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
                        in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
                        in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
                        in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
                        in GestureHandlerRootView (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.tsx:26)
                        in GestureHandlerRootView (at StackView.tsx:454)
                        in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
                        in StackNavigator (at App.js:15)
                        in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
                        in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
                        in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
                        in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:14)
                        in App (created by ExpoRoot)
                        in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
                        in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                        in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
                        in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                        in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
                        in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
                    at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15257:32 in logCapturedError
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15361:20 in logError
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16597:12 in update.callback
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7106:2 in callCallback
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7127:20 in commitUpdateQueue
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15801:25 in commitLifeCycles
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18744:22 in commitLayoutEffects
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18483:29 in commitRootImpl
                    at [native code]:null in commitRootImpl
                    at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18317:17 in commitRoot
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17697:12 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
                    at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5321:31 in runWithPriority$argument_1
                    at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5316:21 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5304:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
                    at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17125:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber


                    Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change permissions to PERMISSIONS in permissionCheck function

Comment: Thanks, but i get this erro now "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'WebRTCModule.peerConnectionInit')" can you tell what this error is?

Comment: is this line correct "const [conn, setConn] = useState(new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080'));" using port 8080

Comment: Try to use useRef instead of useState.

Comment: Anik Dey can we continue this in a chat please, if you have time please?