# React Native: Error [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'WebRTCModule.peerConnectionInit')]

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I get the error in the title after this question was answered:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66800919/react-native-unhandled-promise-rejection-typeerrornull-is-not-an-object-eva
```

Can anybody see where im going wrong in the resource which gives the code?

```
                    Error [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'WebRTCModule.peerConnectionInit')]

                Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:173:8 in registerError
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
                at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:106:4 in printWarning
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:75:16 in error
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19152:9 in warnAboutUpdateOnUnmountedFiberInDEV
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17093:40 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11003:16 in dispatchAction
                at [native code]:null in dispatchAction
                at screens\LoginScreen.js:22:14 in onLogin
                at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
                at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
                at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
                at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
                at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
                at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
                at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
                at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
                at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

                TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'WebRTCModule.peerConnectionInit')

                This error is located at:
                    in CallScreen (at SceneView.tsx:122)
                    in StaticContainer
                    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
                    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
                    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
                    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
                    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
                    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
                    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
                    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
                    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
                    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
                    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
                    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
                    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
                    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
                    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
                    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
                    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
                    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:620)
                    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
                    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:613)
                    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
                    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:495)
                    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
                    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
                    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
                    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
                    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
                    in GestureHandlerRootView (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.tsx:26)
                    in GestureHandlerRootView (at StackView.tsx:454)
                    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
                    in StackNavigator (at App.js:41)
                    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
                    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
                    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
                    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:40)
                    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
                    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
                    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
                    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
                    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
                    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
                at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15257:32 in logCapturedError
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15361:20 in logError
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16597:12 in update.callback
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7106:2 in callCallback
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7127:20 in commitUpdateQueue
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15801:25 in commitLifeCycles
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18744:22 in commitLayoutEffects
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18483:29 in commitRootImpl
                at [native code]:null in commitRootImpl
                at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18317:17 in commitRoot
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17697:12 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
                at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5321:31 in runWithPriority$argument_1
                at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5316:21 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5304:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17125:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11003:16 in dispatchAction
                at [native code]:null in dispatchAction
                at node_modules\@react-navigation\core\src\useSyncState.tsx:38:9 in React.useCallback$argument_0
                at http://192.168.1.102:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:138145:20 in <unknown>
                at node_modules\@react-navigation\core\src\useNavigationHelpers.tsx:43:21 in dispatch
                at node_modules\@react-navigation\core\src\useNavigationCache.tsx:77:12 in dispatch
                at node_modules\@react-navigation\core\src\useNavigationCache.tsx:89:24 in acc.name
                at screens\LoginScreen.js:19:6 in onLogin
                at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
                at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
                at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
                at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
                at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
                at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
                at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
                at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
                at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
                at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
 'use strict';
import ScreenCapturePickerView from './ScreenCapturePickerView';
import RTCPeerConnection from './RTCPeerConnection';
import RTCIceCandidate from './RTCIceCandidate';
import RTCSessionDescription from './RTCSessionDescription';
import RTCView from './RTCView';
import MediaStream from './MediaStream';
import MediaStreamTrack from './MediaStreamTrack';
import mediaDevices from './MediaDevices';
import permissions from './Permissions';

export {
  ScreenCapturePickerView,
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
  MediaStream,
  MediaStreamTrack,
  mediaDevices,
  permissions,
  registerGlobals
};
import {
    RTCPeerConnection,
    RTCIceCandidate,
    RTCSessionDescription,
    RTCView,
    MediaStream,
    MediaStreamTrack,
    mediaDevices,
    registerGloba`enter code here`ls
  } from 'react-native-webrtc';
const remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection()
```